# How to query UPDATE table from ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

While testing I use `Document.last.files.first.purge` from console with rails c, the first file is deleted, but also rails c automatically calls an UPDATE query on the document. But when I call purge on a file from my application, I can see that in the rails server only the DELETE query is launched. (This causes a heap of problems, like server trying to load unexistent blobs, so I assume that it's very important to update a table after changes have been made to it.)
My question is how can I replicate this UPDATE query from ruby?
Thanks!

[image: Expected result from rails server]
 `doc= Document.last`

[image: Real result from rails server]

Code for deleting file:

> Controller (documents_controller.rb)

```
def delete_file_attachment
    @file = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:id]).purge
end
```

> View (_form.html.erb)

```
<div class="files">
    <% @document.files.each do |file| %>
      <%= link_to file.filename, delete_file_attachment_document_url(file.signed_id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

> Model (document.rb)

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :files
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete attachment, you should do something like this:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="files">
    <% @document.files.each do |file| %>
      <%= link_to file.filename, delete_file_attachment_document_url(file), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

**documents_controller.rb**

```
@file = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
@file.purge
```

I hope, that will resolve your issue.

Comment: This did the job.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a where clause on the document with the form thats being changed, and use update_all() to run a SQL query for that specific event. See if something like this works with your Database ->

```
Document.where(conditions).limit(1).update_all(changes) # => 1
```

Here is some documentation on update_all() in Active Record relations
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all